# angular-cli: how to tell browsersync (sockjs-node) which port to use

Tags: angular, angular-cli, browser-sync, sockjs

I'm using angular-cli in combination with ASP.NET. Therefor, I create and angular application, which I'm bnuilding with ng serve, which makes the pageages avalible under

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:4200/i.... (4x)
```

this scripts are embedded in my ASP.NET page which is avalible under `http://localhost:50744/XXXX/XXX` and the application is displayed.

However, the live reload doesn't work because it tries to connect to `http://localhost:50744/sockjs-node/info?t=1528445601999`, so it uses the port of the ASP.NET Site and not the port of 'ng serve'.

**How can I tell sockjs-node to use the 4200 port instead of the 50744?**

**What I tried**: I looked at the browser sync doku (https://browsersync.io/docs/options/ )  I couldn't figure out how to set this with angular-cli.

I'm using `@angular/cli": "~1.7.4"`, `"@angular/core": "^5.2.0",`...

Comment: You can try to run  `ng serve --public-host`

Comment: I had to do `ng serve --publicHost=localhost/MyDirectory/sockjs-node`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using

```
ng build --watch
```

and ran my own watcher (`browser-sync start --proxy "localhost:XXXX" --files "..."`)

Answer (score 0):

ng serve --host [your IP address]